# Fundamental group of the grid in $\mathbb{R}^2$ isomorphic with commutator subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-groups

I'm having trouble with the following exercise:

> Show that the fundamental group of the grid of integer lines
>   $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x\in\mathbb{Z}\lor y\in\mathbb{Z})$
>   isomorphic with the commutator subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$,
>   the free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.

I know that the abelianization of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and the abelianization $G_{ab}$ of a group $G$ is $G/[G,G]$.. but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Any advice as to how to approach this problem is appreciated!

Comment: Realize the grid as the cover of the wedge of $2$ circles associated, via the classification of covering spaces, to the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$. You don't have to do this if you can just show that both groups are isomorphic to the free group on countably many generators, but to my mind this is the cleanest and most natural proof, since it explains what this result "means."

Comment: The exercise right above it actually asks to construct a covering map from the grid to the 8-figure, that's is regular with autmorphism group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, so I'm sure that's not a coincidence. I'm not sure how these things connect really though..

Comment: I guess I'm supposed to take as the cover $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to S^1\times S^1$, $u(x,y)=(e^{2\pi i x}, e^{2\pi i y})$ and restrict it to $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x\in\mathbb{Z}\lor y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Then the image would be $\{(e^{2\pi i x},1)\in\mathbb{C}^2:x\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(1,e^{2\pi i y})\in\mathbb{C}^2:y\in\mathbb{R}\}=S^1\vee S^1$

Comment: Another exercise tells me that $u$ is regular with automorphism group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Maybe I'm just tired, but I don't see how all these facts connect. I haven't done this kind of exercise before, so I don't really know what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the wedge of two circles, and note that $\pi_1(X) \cong F_2$.

First note that $\mathbb Z^2$ acts transitively on the grid, and that in fact the grid is just $\tilde{X}/[F_2,F_2]$, and in fact this is the Cayley graph for $\mathbb Z^2$.

Then, we know that $[F_2,F_2] \cong \pi_1([\tilde{X}/[F_2,F_2]) \cong F_{\infty}$.

The previous fact can be checked by noting that we have an isomorphism $\pi_1(Y)/p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X}) \cong\pi_1(Y)\cong G$ where the first isomorphism follows since the universal cover is contractible, and the second follows from basic covering space theory, with reference [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/slides/Gt-l4sh.pdf).